# Sending $emit / $broadcast from several diffentes parts of the code and itercept them in one place

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I send $emits* (or $broadcasts for that matter) from diferent parts of the code and different controllers and intercept these broadcasts or emits from one place only. 
It seems to work fine but I wonder if it's a bad practice (sending several $emit to be intercepted by the same $on) or whether it affects the performance or maybe it's just something that has a negative effect that I'm missing.

Here's an example below of how I send $emits from different places and intercept from the same $on.

*In this example controller 1 is child of controller 2 and that's why I use $emit instead of $broadcast.

Cotroller1:

```
  $scope.updateSelectionLine = function(slip, offset) {
    BetSlipFactory.updateSelectionLine(slip, offset).then(function() {
      $scope.$emit('lines:accordionChanged');
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
   };

    $scope.updateSelectionLine = function(availableBetTypes) {
      if (availableBetTypes.length) {
        $scope.$emit('lines:accordionChanged');
      }
    }
```

Controller 2:

```
$scope.$on('lines:accordionChanged', function() {
  $scope.refreshLines();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Emitting events is not a bad practice in itself; on the contrary, it is the recommended pattern for communication between different 'unrelated' components. Now that said, it is common to see that feature abused or overused. When determining whether to use pub/sub eventing, I usually check the following list as a minimum:

- Is there another way of doing the same thing in a simple manner?
- Where would I publish my event? I tend to stick to publishing from services/providers only and subscribe from controllers.

The cases for which I use this pattern:

- When I am trying to implement cross-module communication without coupling them to each other. For example, I might have an auth module that emits Auth::LoggedIn and Auth::LoggedOut events so that other modules in the application can subscribe to them and react accordingly.
- When I am trying to keep data from multiple controllers in sync. In this case, I create a service which 'owns' the data and multiple controllers that use/alter it. When data changes, the service emits an event and the consuming controllers listen to it and update as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing is fine,  there are not a ton of performance issues with using $emit or $broadcast except that I would avoid doing $rootScope.$emit() or $broadcast().  These are really highly optimized calls and would not recommend polluting your root scope for them.

The other line of thinking is if $scope.refreshLines() could some how be packed in as a service you could inject into each respective controller.  If this is a directive you are going to use a ton of on a single page I would recommend going with a service since the $scope.refreshLines() will trigger for each instance of the directive.  If you are not going to use this more then 2-3 times on a page the performance hit is minimal.